# What are named and default arguments?

Tags: scala

I heard that Scala contains a feature called named and default arguments but I don't know what such parameters do or how to use them.

Can someone explain their usage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some special functions call type in Scala

**Named arguments:**

Named arguments allow you to pass arguments to a function in a different order.For example:

```
def speed(distance: Float, time: Float): Float = distance / time
```

And the it can be used like this:

```
speed(distance = 100, time = 10)
```

or

```
speed(time = 10, distance = 100)
```

**Default arguments:**

Scala lets you specify default values for function parameters. For example:

```
def printTime(out: java.io.PrintStream = Console.out) =
    out.println("time = "+ System.currentTimeMillis())
```

Then you can call printTime without giving any output stream like this:

```
printTime()
```

**Repeated arguments:**

Scala allows you to indicate that the last parameter to a function may be repeat. For example:

```
def echo(args: String*) =
   for (arg <- args)
     println(arg)
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
echo()
echo("one")
echo("hello", "world!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Default arguments solve the problem other programming languages normally solve with method overloading. When there is a method

```
def addNumbers(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int, d: Int) = a+b+c+d
```

that takes multiple parameters it can be useful to set some default values in overloaded methods to provide an API that is easier to use if one doesn't want to fill all parameters:

```
def addNumbers(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int) = addNumbers(a, b, c, 0)
def addNumbers(a: Int, b: Int) = addNumbers(a, b, 0, 0)
```

With default arguments it is no longer necessary to overload such a method:

```
def addNumbers(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int = 0, d: Int = 0) = a+b+c+d
```

The compiler automatically calls the method with the specific default arguments if they are not specified:

```
scala> addNumbers(1, 2, 3)
res2: Int = 6
```

A useful place for default arguments is in constructors. It is easier to write

```
class A(i: Int, s: String = "")
```

than

```
class A(i: Int, s: String) {
  def this(i: Int) = this(i, "")
}
```

---

Named arguments on the other side can improve the readability of a method call:

```
def compute(xs: List[Int], executeInParallel: Boolean) = ???
```

`compute(xs, executeInParallel = true)` is easier to read than only `compute(xs, true)`

One can always specify the name of a parameter regardless of its order. This means `compute(executeInParallel = true, xs = xs)` is the same as `compute(xs, true)`. The compiler often just needs a hint which parameter must be placed at which position when the ordering of the parameters is changed.

---

A use case where both named and default arguments can be used lies in the copy method of case classes, which are automatically generated by the compiler:

```
scala> case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
defined class Person

scala> val p = Person("Ruben", 43)
p: Person = Person(Ruben,43)

scala> val oneYearOlder = p.copy(age = p.age+1)
oneYearOlder: Person = Person(Ruben,44)
```

---

It may be important to mention that named arguments only work for methods defined in Scala. Parameters of methods defined in Java can't be called by their name.

Furthermore named arguments don't work on function literals:

```
scala> val f = (i: Int) => i
f: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> f(i = 1)
<console>:9: error: not found: value i
              f(i = 1)
                ^
```

For further information to this feature one can take a look to [docs.scala-lang.org](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/completed/named-and-default-arguments.html).